# Edit value of variable in a if-statment argument depending of the if-statments outcome

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop, if-statement, woocommerce

What I'm trying to do is to contact WooCommerce every fifth seconds to check if a product have been edited. I can do that by asking for res[0].date_modified. Then I compare the time it was created (res[0].date_created) and last modified.

If the values are the same the product have never been modified. However if the product get modified I no longer want to compare the time the product was created and last modifed.

I now want to compare the time with the last time it got modified with "res[0].date_modified" so I can see if it gets modified another time.

This is what I have come up with:

```
function lookForEdit(){

WooCommerce.get('products/',  function(err, WooData, res) {
    res=JSON.parse(res)

    var comp = res[0].date_created;

    if(comp == res[0].date_modified){
        console.log("the product haven't been modified")
    }
    else{
        console.log("The product have been edited")
        comp = res[0].date_modified;
    }
})
}

setInterval(lookForEdit, 5000);
```

I understand why it doesn't work, but I don't know how to fix it.

How can I fix it?

Thanks

Also  I asked this question last week and thought I got an answer that would work. The answer I got:

```
var comp;


function lookForEdit(){

WooCommerce.get('products/',  function(err, WooData, res) {
    res=JSON.parse(res)
    //console.log(res[0])
    
    if(comp == undefined){
        console.log("The product haven't been editet")
        comp = res[0].date_created;
    }
    if(comp != res[0].date_modified){
        comp = res[0].date_modified;
        console.log("The product have been edited")
        //editAPI(res[0])
        
    }

    


});
};
```

Then I realised that this wouldn't work when I put the function inside a for-loop to check multiple items. I can't use "comp" if checking index 0 and index 1.

Thank you again!

What I want to achive

```
var comp;


function lookForEdit(){

WooCommerce.get('products/',  function(err, WooData, res) {
    res=JSON.parse(res)
    for(var i = 0; i < res.length; i++ ){

    if(comp == undefined){
        console.log("The product haven't been editet")
        comp = res[i].date_created;
    }
    if(comp != res[i].date_modified){
        comp = res[i].date_modified;
        console.log("The product have been edited")
        //editAPI(res[i])

    }
}



});
};
```

Comment: where is your for-loop?

Comment: I haven't included it here. I haven't even written it but I understand it wouldn't work. But I can add it to the question so you get what I'm trying to achive.

Comment: use `setTimeout(lookForEdit, 5000);`  instead of `setInterval`  and put it at the end of the `lookForEdit()`  function  to loop endlessly

Comment: I have never user setTimeout before, what matter would it make? the loop runs endlessly anyway? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store multiple values in the variable `comp`, using an array or an object. In this case, instead of assigning the value with `comp = res[0].date_modified`, you can use `comp[0] = res[0].date_modified`.

Full example:

```
var comp = {};

function lookForEdit(){

WooCommerce.get('products/',  function(err, WooData, res) {

    res=JSON.parse(res)

    for (var i = 0; i < res.length; ++i) {
        //console.log(res[i])

        if(comp[i] == undefined){
            console.log("The product haven't been editet")
            comp[i] = res[i].date_created;
        }
        if(comp[i] != res[i].date_modified){
            comp[i] = res[i].date_modified;
            console.log("The product have been edited")
            //editAPI(res[i])    
        }
    }
});
};
```

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

You can use function closures to maintain the state of the product i.e. is it new of old.

```
var checkIfModified = function() {
    var isNew = true;
    return function() {
        var dateProp = isNew ? 'date_created' : 'date_modified';
        var time = test.shift();
        if( time !== product[dateProp]) {
            product.modified = time;
            isNew = false;
            console.log( 'modified')
        } else {
            console.log('it is same');
        }
    }
}

var lookForEdit = checkIfModified();
for( /*your for loop to check for edit*/ ) {
    lookForEdit();
}
```

Comment: To be fair, using a closure is a more idiomatic, elegant solution than mine.